# Terminal closing on using 'login' command

Tags: bash, login

I am using Centos 6.6.
Whenever I use `login <username>`, the terminal shuts down.
But when I use `su - <username>` it works fine. Also I tried doing the same on a SSH session and the session closes when I use `login <username>` but works perfectly if I use `su - <username>`.
Has anyone else faced this issue before?
If so, please share the solution for the same.

Answer (score 9):

> [`man login`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/login.1.html)
>
> > **BUGS**
> >
> > > A recursive login, as used to be possible in the good old days, no longer works; for most purposes [`su`(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html) is a satisfactory substitute. Indeed, for security reasons, `login` does a [*`vhangup()`*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vhangup.2.html) system call to remove any possible listening processes on the tty. This is to avoid password sniffing. If one uses the command `login`, then the surrounding shell gets killed by *`vhangup()`* because it's no longer the true owner of the tty. This can be avoided by using `exec login` in a top-level shell or `xterm`.