# Linux: print disappears for an executable in rc.local

Tags: linux, printf, autostart, rc.local

I have an executable program /home/user/**foo** with root and executable permissions. The **foo** has 3 threads and performs outputs using **printf**.
This program is placed in embedded target with Linux, 4.1.22-ltsi.
I need to run the **foo** automatically on target startup.
For that I added the following line in file **/etc/rc.local**

```
# new line 
/home/user/foo > /dev/ttyS0 &
#old line 
exit 0
```

As the result, the foo runs, but there is problem with printings.
The prints appears after starting rc.local

```
Starting /etc/rc.local  Compatibility ...
```

**but has been disappear after reboot complete**. Just after reboot output

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9 linaro-developer ttyS0
```

the prints are eliminated.
The command

```
 ps -aux | grep foo
```

shows that tty is **?**
Also, I checked current tty' console:

```
$ tty
/dev/ttyS0
```

I also tried some other options in the rc.local, **but them do not output at all**:

```
/home/user/foo 2>&1 &
```

and

```
/home/user/foo &
```

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218600/5132 .

Comment: JdeBP, I'm relatively new in Linux and I do not understand solution for the my case